# jQuery how to append data in loop only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with loops and I add data in to table, from buttons.
So each time it creates 5 cells for me, but I need to append data only one time after button click.

Code:

```js
$('.next').on('click', function () {
    $('.changeoverTable').show();
    var arrNumber = new Array();
    $('input[type=text]').each(function (i) {
        arrNumber.push($(this).val());
            $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + arrNumber[i] + '</td></tr>'); 
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of data"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of nest"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
   <table class="changeoverTable hide">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3">Table</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

As you can see, each time after click ok, i got 5 rows, **but i need only one, from each input field.**

Comment: I'm very confused, When I press the button,  shall i create 1 row for every input or 1 row in total with 1 td for every input?

Comment: Pls show screenshot what do you want

Comment: @RyanNghiem What would a screenshot help, you already have the code available?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen from one input field one row at table, as u can see now, after click ok, it's create 5 rows, but i need one

Comment: @qunz666 When I click on an `OK` button I get 4 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a if condition `if(arrNumber[i]){` check if value exists.

```js
$('.next').on('click', function () {
    $('.changeoverTable').show();
    var arrNumber = new Array();
    $(".changeoverTable > tbody").html('');
    $('input[type=text]').each(function (i) {
    
        arrNumber.push($(this).val());
        if(arrNumber[i]){
            $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + arrNumber[i] + '</td></tr>'); 
            }
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of data"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of nest"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
   <table class="changeoverTable hide">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3">Table</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  $('.changeoverTable').show();
  $('.changeoverTable tbody tr').remove();
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val()) $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + $(this).val() + '</td></tr>');
  })
});
```

Please notice that I've added `$('.changeoverTable tbody tr').remove();` to remove the old records in the table.

Also there is no reason to use an `Array` for this.

**Demo**

```js
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  $('.changeoverTable').show();
  $('.changeoverTable tbody tr').remove();
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val()) $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + $(this).val() + '</td></tr>');
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of data"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of nest"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
<table class="changeoverTable hide">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope this will works for you.

```js
$('.next').on('click', function () {
    $('.changeoverTable').show();
 var arrNumber = new Array();
 var test = $(this).prev('input').val();
 console.log('value', test);
 if(test != ''){
     $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + test + '</td></tr>'); 
 }else{
  alert('empty data');
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>C3.js</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of data"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of nest"><button class="next">ok</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="next">ok</button>
   <table class="changeoverTable hide">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Table</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.next').on('click', function () {
    $('.changeoverTable').show();
    var arrNumber = new Array();
    var check=0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function (i) {
if(check==0){
        arrNumber.push($(this).val());
            $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + 
arrNumber[i] + '</td></tr>');
}
 check=1; 
    })
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.